# Data Annotation for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-annotations, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am going to develop a machine learning model. I have large data sets(Text). I need overall better accuracy F1 score etc. I am using data annotation tools(Dataturks). Which approach will be good to label the data as single label per entity or multiple label per entity (like there has been 5 times GUI so we have to label it 1 time or 5 times for better overall score). Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I'm a bit confused what you're asking

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have a data set (large text) I want to label it for machine learning model using dataturks. There are entities which repeat multiples times like WI-Fi so for better results could i label it multiples times or one time is enough. Thank you.

Comment: If you have any duplicate examples where all the features are identical you need to remove them

Comment: Okay, I'll put this as an answer so you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any duplicate examples where all the features are identical you need to remove them